# Fourier coefficients and sequence $\{\frac1n\}$

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have seen some references, which indicate that Fourier coefficients of a function $f$, denoted by  $c_n(f)$, have some connections with the sequence $\{\frac{1}{n}\}$. Like [here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Fourier_transform_of_a_generalized_function)  [and here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series), it seems that $c_n(f) \le \text{const}\,  \frac{1}{n}$.

Are there any known results related to this question? Fourier coefficients must have been well-studied in many cases, but it is not my expertise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is of bounded variation than the inequality is valid. Ref.  Fourier series by Edwards.

Comment: could you indicate a little bit more specific in which part of the book? I am considering a two dimensional function (bounded continuous), so, if I can get a ``universal`` constant, it will be better.

Comment: There cannot be a universal constant. If $g(x)=\lambda f(x)$ then $c_n(g)=\lambda c_n(f)$.

Comment: @nicomezi  Actually, I have some specific functions of two variables. If I can get the specific form of the constant, in my case, I may get the constant I want